# Como compilar proyecto en python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, compilacion

tengo un proyecto en `Python` en el cual uso un `entorno virtual`. Cuando uso el `pyinstaller` los archivos compilados se hacen demasiado pesados. Necesito saber si existe alguna manera de compilar un proyecto en `Python` de la manera mas optima posible, evitando instalar archivos incluidos en las dependencias que no se usen en el archivo `main.py` ni en niguno otro. En el proyecto estoy usando `PyGame`.

Comment: `pyinstaller` justamente hace lo que pides, analiza los imports y se encarga de armar un paquete de distribución con, el interprete python, tu código y todos los paquetes que tienes declarados. En lenguajes interpretados y de alto nivel como Python, la distribución de cualquier aplicación ocupa bastante espacio.